# Download image from google

Tags: java, android, eclipse

All I am trying to do is to download the image from the URL and display it, but it always shows the toast message. Any help is appreciated, thank you in advance.

Here is the code that I currently have :

```
public class CopyOfMainGoogle extends Activity {

    @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.copygoogleactivity);
         new DownloadImageTask((ImageView)       findViewById(R.id.imageView1)).execute("https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRyIxW1ckzzIsvhUX3SCQTlPWVX2MlIBE8rvTIzgMaPeHkjT778hSM9hfn2");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_google, menu);
        return true;
    }

    private class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
        ImageView bmImage;

        public DownloadImageTask(ImageView bmImage) {
            this.bmImage = bmImage;
            Log.i("debug","reached here");
        }

        protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
            String urldisplay = urls[0];
            Bitmap mIcon11 = null;
            try {
              InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
              mIcon11 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                                Toast.makeText(CopyOfMainGoogle.this, R.string.Toast, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                         });

            }
            return mIcon11;
         }

        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
             bmImage.setImageBitmap(result);
            findViewById(R.id.progressBar1).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
      }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this

Comment: Are you getting any error when trying to Toast ? You cannot perform any UI action while `doInBackground`, UI actions are performed in `onPostExecute`

Comment: You can display a toast even from a background thread , all you need is the reference of a context.

Comment: did you add <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> to your AndroidManifest.xml ?

Comment: You should toast the exception message. Not a predefined sting. Or tell what the log statement there prints out. But you are using https instead of http and https will not work out of the box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you haven't added

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

to your `AndroidManifest.xml`, please add it and see if it resolves.

Also,this is not important, but if you'd like try using

```
 new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openConnection().getInputStream();
```

instead of just using `new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();`

Comment: Do NOT call onPostExecute and doInBackground directly. So wrong!

Comment: @greenapps, Thanks for that,I'm also new to android development.Anyways, in this post, DownloadImageTask().execute(url) is working fine. Edited my answer.

Comment: new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openConnection().getInputStream(); did the trick :)

thank you :D